# img comparison slider mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, slider

I've got a question about the img comparison slider from kavya sukumar. I already asked there in the issue thread. But i'm not sure if she's still active.

So I took her image slider for my website. It works fine in desktop version but in mobile it won't work. My Question is now, if somebody knows how I can fix it, so it'll work in mobile?

Here is my website:
http://486755-10.web1.fh-htwchur.ch/

It would be awesome if someone could help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For Mobile device make the container width:100% as well as images. Don't use fixed width, try to use percentage for mobile devices and this will support all mobile viewports.
Ex: Remove image width:500px and try to change in 100%

This will make responsive and supportive.

Comment: Thank you. But it won't change the thing, that the slider isnt working on mobile. I think it's something with the touch-function.. cause in desktop version you have the mouse.